# sendgrid integration in classic asp

Tags: email, asp-classic, sendgrid, email-client

I want to integrate **SendGrid** smtp email to send mail from my Classic asp application. I have no idea about how to integrate third party mail server.
I only used gmail server to send mail from application.

If I register on sendgrid with mail id xyz@gmail.com then which credential i need to use for userid and password. Do i need to use sendgrid credential for below example:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irYZ3.png)

Which credential i need to use in yellow circle.
link for above example [Example link](http://theholmesoffice.com/using-sendgrid-with-classic-asp-to-send-emails/)

I read docs provided on sendgrid official site, but idea is not cleared how to use it.

Please help on this..

thanks 
sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an account with SendGrid then presumably you have a username and password to log in to it - you just need to use these as the values in the yellow box.

Their example is actually pretty standard cdo.message code.  If you have got it to work with gmail then you should be able to modify your existing gmail code.  SendGrid also appears to use port 465 so all you would need to change is the smtp server address and the username and password.

See this page
http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/sending_email_asp.php

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am using sendGrid credentials but now I am getting new error "The message could not be send to the SMTP server, the transprot error code was ...... The server response is not available". also my account for sendgrid is not yet activated, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here, but if your sendgrid account isn't activated that may be why.  I've no experience with sendgrid but quite a lot with cdo in general.  A frequent error message is "The transport failed to connect with the server".  It sounds as if you've got beyond that, the transport is connecting with the server but the server is rejecting the message, which is what you would expect if your account needs to be activated

Comment: Yes, account is not activated thats y i'm getting error. I got support mail from sendgrid, they told me that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party.. That link is not longer working.
This is the solution on how to send emails with SendGrid in Classic ASP.

```
Set oMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
iConf.Fields.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = {your API key}
iConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = {your password}
iConf.Fields.Update
Set oMail.Configuration = iConf
oMail.To = {to}

oMail.From = {from}
oMail.Subject = {subject}
oMail.HTMLBody  = {htmlmessage}
oMail.TextBody = {textmessage}
oMail.Send
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
set omail=nothing
```